# Accessing Global Vars & Functions in custom php page

Tags: php

I have created a php page called "test.php" and uploaded this file to the root
folder of my wordpress installation.

This file contains only this:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { blah..... }  ?>
```

I need to check if user is logged in and if so, get some details.

So what I need to know is what wp file(s) I need to include in my php file to be able to get the results of this function and also I prob need to check on an id, username.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following code to the top of the PHP file will give you access to the Wordpress functions and global variables.

```
<?php include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php' );
```

You should then be able to run normal Wordpress functions to determine whether or not the user is logged in:

```
<?php 
global $user_ID; 
get_currentuserinfo();
if ($user_ID) {
    // Do Something 
}
?>
```